# Power BI - Powerpoint Export is Not even Showing

Tags: powerpoint, powerbi, powerpoint-2010

I was going to try to export a template I created to powerpoint. But when I go to the export option I only get one option in export which is only to a powerbi template.  As note: I'm still on Office 2010 with no chance of changing it and have the most recent version of powerbi.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Export to PowerPoint` option is available on [Power BI Web](https://app.powerbi.com), but not Power BI Desktop. You can choose the report you want to export, click `File` and then `Export to PowerPoint`.

[image: export to ppt]

Thus, you have to publish the report to Power BI web to use this function.

Details: [Export reports from Power BI to PowerPoint (Preview)](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-publish-to-powerpoint/)